# Неправильный порядок вывода информации о сотруднике

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть сотрудник, который работает в подразделении, но у каждого подразделения есть подчиняющиеся ему 
отделы (подразделения). Проблема в том, что когда сотрудник работает в (Главном подразделении), то мой запрос работает так: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b253c/2

> 1 | Иванов Иван Иванович | Главное подразделение | (null)

Но когда сотрудник работает в подчиняющемся отделе (Главного подразделения), то запрос выводит следующее: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/354e7/2

> 1 | Иванов Иван Иванович | Подчиняюсь главному подразделению | Главное
>   подразделение

А я хочу, чтобы в данном случае (когда сотрудник работает в подчиняющемся отделении) выводило так:

> 1 | Иванов Иван Иванович | Главное подразделение | Подчиняюсь главному
>   подразделению

Как сделать такой порядок вывода?

Вот моя схема БД:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/494eb/2

Comment: Спасибо, большое)